# How to insert Data into a custom type oracle table from a source table

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-data-types

I have a source data table like below:

```
create table source_qtr (
 id   int
,qtr1 NUMBER(20,9)
,qtr2 NUMBER(20,9)
,qtr3 NUMBER(20,9)
,qtr4 NUMBER(20,9)     );
```

insert scripts for sample data

```
insert into source_qtr values (1,1.982,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
insert into source_qtr values (2,2.93482,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
insert into source_qtr values (3,3.982,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
insert into source_qtr values (4,7.982,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
insert into source_qtr values (5,5.982,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
insert into source_qtr values (6,9.982,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
insert into source_qtr values (7,11.982,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
insert into source_qtr values (8,12.982,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
insert into source_qtr values (9,21.982,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
insert into source_qtr values (10,41.982,2.3453,5.3453,4.64564);
```

And my target table structure depends on few more objects those are:

```
create type obj_qtr as Object   ( qtr_id      int
                                , qtr_value   NUMBER(20,9)    );
```

```
CREATE TYPE VARR_QTR IS VARRAY(4) OF obj_qtr;
```

```
CREATE TABLE TAR_QTR            ( SRC_id       int
                                , QTR          VARR_QTR);
```

I can insert the data in to this target table by using manually generated insert scripts:

```
insert into TAR_QTR values (1, VARR_QTR(obj_qtr('1','1.982'),obj_qtr('2','2.3453'),obj_qtr('3','5.3453'),obj_qtr('4','4.64564')));
```

This process is taking more time. To avoid that, we are trying to create a procedure to insert this data from the source table:

```
create or replace procedure Data_Load_proc
is
begin
       for x in (   select   sq.id
                    ,        'VARR_QTR     (     obj_qtr(''1'',''' || sq.qtr1 || ''')
                                           ,     obj_qtr(''2'',''' || sq.qtr2 || ''')
                                           ,     obj_qtr(''3'',''' || sq.qtr3 || ''')
                                           ,     obj_qtr(''4'',''' || sq.qtr4 || ''')
                                           )' as a            
                    from     source_qtrsq
                ) loop
           insert into TAR_QTR (SRC_id,QTR) values (x.id,cast(x.a as VARR_QTR));
       end loop;
       commit;
End;
```

When I execute this procedure I got error:

```
Error starting at line : 60 in command - 
BEGIN procedure Data_Load_proc; END; 
Error report - 
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following: 

          ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma 
            raise return select update while with <an identifier> 
            <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << 
            continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback 
            savepoint set sql execute commit for all merge pipe purge 
ORA-06550: line 1, column 36: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: 

   ; 
06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s" 
*Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. 
*Action:
```

How to resolve this issue? Or is there any other way to insert this data?

Note: not able to use 'External table' or 'sql Loader' due to some security reason.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you should read about ways of executing pl/sql code in sqlplus or your ide.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you need to cast the source table rows into OBJ_QTR types, and that table is not structured to do that nicely. So you need a query which changes the projection to fit the target structure:

```
select  id, 1 as qtr_id, qtr1 as qtr_value from source_qtr union all
select  id, 2 as qtr_id, qtr2 as qtr_value from source_qtr union all
select  id, 3 as qtr_id, qtr3 as qtr_value from source_qtr union all
select  id, 4 as qtr_id, qtr4 as qtr_value from source_qtr
```

Now you can use that to populate type instances and multiset() to populate your VARRAY. Something like this:

```
insert into tar_qtr 
select m.id,
        CAST (MULTISET (select OBJ_QTR(qtr_id, qtr_value) as qtr 
           from (
                  select  id, 1 as qtr_id, qtr1 as qtr_value from source_qtr union all
                  select  id, 2 as qtr_id, qtr2 as qtr_value from source_qtr union all
                  select  id, 3 as qtr_id, qtr3 as qtr_value from source_qtr union all
                  select  id, 4 as qtr_id, qtr4 as qtr_value from source_qtr
               ) q where q.id = m.id) as VARR_QTR)
from    (select distinct id from source_qtr) m
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much.., 

This post helped me to understand the issue which i made in my code.

But, Do we have any other way to insert this data, Because this process is also taking more time to complete the insert, sometime it is not even responding back.

Thanks

Comment: we have around 15L records in the source table.